# upload file and get path of it angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload

How can i upload file then save a copy of it an folder in my project then send the path of this file to API [As file is string in API] using Angular 4 .. i don't want to use 3rd party .. I read this artical " **http://www.bentedder.com/upload-images-angular-4-without-plugin/** " but i got errors at

```
this.projectService.upload(formData,this.project.id).subscribe(res => {
            // do stuff w/my uploaded file
        });
```

as i don't understand what's **project.id** ... 
 any help for uploading file generally  ?

Comment: Project id it's a parameter of his upload method.

Comment: project should have any declaration ?

Comment: you could have this.myUploaderService.upload(file).subscribe ... you define that you want name of service, name of methode, method's parameters, etw

Comment: @AyaAbdelaziz `this.project.id` is an id parameter for that project , it can be anyother unique identifier for your project.